# SqlException: Procedure or function sqQuestion_AddNewQuestion has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I am trying to enter some data into a local SQL Server database. However, despite counting the number of parameters numerous times, I still get this error:

> Procedure or function sqQuestion_AddNewQuestion has too many arguments specified

The problem occurs in `SqlDataAccess.SaveDataInTransaction`. Many other questions about this have involved a foreach loop causing the problem, however I am not using one.

I am quite new to C# so maybe I'm missing the obvious.

Code is as follows:

dbo.Questions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Topic] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Title] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Description] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    [AuthorId] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
    [Image] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [CreatedDate] DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT getutcdate()
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sqQuestion_AddNewQuestion]
    @Topic nvarchar(50),
    @Title nvarchar(50),
    @Description nvarchar(200),
    @AuthorId nvarchar(128),
    @CreatedDate datetime2,
    @Image nvarchar(Max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.Questions(Topic, Title, [Description], AuthorId, CreatedDate, [Image])
    VALUES (@Topic, @Title, @Description, @AuthorId, @CreatedDate, @Image)
END
```

QuestionDbModel:

```
public class QuestionDbModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

QuestionModel (used for allowing users to upload an image):

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Dashboard Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(QuestionModel question)
{
    var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(question.ImageFile.FileName);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(question.ImageFile.FileName);
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + ext;

    var path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/QuestionImages/", fileName);

    using (var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        question.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(filestream);
    }

    QuestionDbModel newQuestion = new QuestionDbModel
        {
            Topic = question.Topic,
            Title = question.Title,
            Description = question.Description,
            Image = fileName,
            AuthorId = question.AuthorId,
            CreatedDate = question.CreatedDate
        };

    try
    {
        _sqlDataAccess.StartTransaction("*DAtabaseName*");

        _sqlDataAccess.SaveDataInTransaction("dbo.sqQuestion_AddNewQuestion", newQuestion);

        _sqlDataAccess.CommitTransaction();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        _sqlDataAccess.RollbackTransation();
        throw;
    }
}
```

SqlDataAccess (SaveDataInTransaction):

```
public void SaveDataInTransaction<T>(string storedProcedure, T parameters)
{
    _connection.Execute(storedProcedure, parameters,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: _transaction);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class "QuestionDbModel" does not match the list of expected parameters. As a test, try creating another class that has just the properties that match the list of parameters the stored procedure is expecting. If that solves the problem, then you may decide to use inheritance or an interface that is backed by the "QuestionDbModel" class, but only exposes the 6 properties/parameters.

Comment: I removed the List<CommentModel> Comments and the Id properties and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. :D